# How to pass streamed file contents as json structure to AJAX in Flask app

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, flask

I have the following Flask app which is basically just a form where you upload a file, select from a few options (radio buttons), and a python script in the backend processes the uploaded file to produce an HTML.

At the moment, I'm streaming this uploaded file by reading it to memory instead of saving it local (since I will be deploying this app to a read-only file system). I process this streamed file into a dictionary via `csv.DictReader(...)` and then turn this into a JSON object. I then want to pass this JSON object to the AJAX function in `index.html` so that my backend python script could process the JSON file instead of a locally-saved file.

**Question: What's the right way to pass the JSON structure to AJAX and then on the AJAX end, how do I pass the JSON object back to my next Flask route (`upload_vals()`) where I kick off the python script?**

**main.py**

```
@app.route('/process_file', methods=['POST'])
def process_file():
    # Run checks on the file
    if 'file' not in flask.request.files or not flask.request.files['file'].filename:
        return flask.jsonify({'result':'False', 'message':'no files selected'})
        return flask.redirect(url_for('home'))
    file = flask.request.files['file']
    filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
    if not allowed_file(file.filename):
        return flask.jsonify({'result':'False', 'message':'Must be TXT file!'})
        return flask.redirect(url_for('home'))

    # Convert streamed file contents to json object
    contents_dict = csv.DictReader(file, delimiter='\t')
    data = []
    for line in contents_dict:
        data.append(line)
    json_data = json.dumps(data)

    # Stream file and check that places exist
    contents = csv.reader(file, delimiter='\t') 
    if not places_exist(contents):
        return flask.jsonify({'result':'False', 'message':'There is an affiliation missing from your Place list. Please re-try.'})
        return flask.redirect(url_for('home'))
    flask.session['filename'] = filename
    return flask.jsonify({'result':'True'})
    return json_data # is this right?
```

**index.html**

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#TheForm').on('click', '.submit_data', function(){
         var form_data = new FormData($('#myform')[0]);
         var flag = true;
         $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: '/process_file',
           data: form_data,
           contentType: false,
           cache: false,
           processData: false,
           success: function(data) {
             if (data.result === 'False'){
                $('.error_message').html(data.message)
                flag = false;
             }
             else {
                var payload = {};
               $('.form-radio').each(function(){
                  if ($(this).prop('checked')){
                    payload[$(this).data('key')] = $(this).data('value');
                  }
               });
               $.ajax({
                 url: "/upload_vals",
                 type: "get",
                 data: {'payload':JSON.stringify(payload)},
                 success: function(response) {
                   $(".my-results").html(response.data);
                 },
                });
             }
          },
       });
    });
  });
</script>
```